# AJAX Javascript Element not updating

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an issue with the Internet Explorer/EDGE browser. Basically, I have a script that pulls data from a remote XML file and displays it in page (live example: http://www.oldiesplus.com/ - The Radio info section, top of the page)

The way it works is that every 15 seconds, the XML file is read and the Song Title is updated (that's the scrolling bit). This works perfectly in Google Chrome, under IE/EDGE, however, the script executes (see Console log) but the element is never updated.

The XML file is grabbed using Curl and CURLOPT_FRESH_CONTENT is set to true.

The question being then, why is the element not updating with the new content in IE/EDGE?

Here's some code to help:

sc_conn.inc (PHP):

```
$ch             = curl_init($sc_host . '/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $sc_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $sc_admin.':'.$sc_pass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    $curl = curl_exec($ch);
```

shoutcast.js (JavaScript):

```
function getStreamData() {
        var ajax;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        ajax.open('GET','/sc_data.php', true);
        ajax.send();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                        var data = ajax.responseText.split("|");
                        var song = (data[1] == '') ? 'some music.' : data[1];
                        var cta = (player_state == 0) ? '/new/img/play.png' : '/new/img/pause.png';
                        if (data[2]) {
                                document.getElementById('radio-info').innerHTML = '<h2>'+data[2]+'</h2>';
                                document.getElementById('radio-info').innerHTML += '<p><span class="dj_name">'+data[0]+' is playing</span> '+song+'</p>';
                        }else{
                                document.getElementById('radio-info').innerHTML = '<p><span class="dj_name">'+data[0]+' is playing</span> '+song+'</p>';
                        }
                        document.getElementById('tunein').src = cta;
                        console.log("Title Updated!");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: most probably you have problem with  `ajax` request, i would suggest you to use `jQuery` ajax method for making your ajax request instead writing it with simple js - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, jquery is free and supported in all major browsers

Comment: have you debug your code using console.log() ? try to find where stuck

Comment: show your `console.log(data)` output

Comment: you have a function called `checkBrowser()` in your js file, where you have   some code for IE, but that function is not being called anywhere ?

Comment: To address the above comments:

Armen: I'd rather hope to avoid jQuery as the scope of the project doesn't justify bringing in an entire library, plus I'm not up to speed with jQuery

Kishan: I've added in a Console.log at the end of the function, which it reaches correctly. The element just does not seem to update in IE/Edge when it does in Chrome/Firefox.

SearchAndResQ: The checkBrowser() function was there to display a Flash-based audio player, this is no longer in use and the function should be removed. It currently has nothing to with the issue I'm having.

Comment: It is being displayed( without scroll ), if you select the line of text after "ERSA is Playing" you can see it.(Like: ERSA is playing George Michael - Monkey). Something to do with the css

Comment: @SearhAndResQ: The CSS? Hmm I hadn't considered that. I will play around with it and report back here.

Comment: The resolution was to disable caching of the AJAX request - appending a random number to the end of the call of the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution was to circumvent caching of the AJAX request - appending a random number to the end of the call of the PHP script using:

```
Math.random();
```